# I cant light up the interior of an object

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, light, lighting

Hey all I am making a spaceship in blender cycles and when I was adding lights to the back compartment of my ship for some reason in the quick render mode there are lights and in the actual render mode that you use to export it's basically pitch black! I have no idea how to fix this I have suns, and emission materials on the wall of the ship but no light. I need help!

This is quick render:
[image]

actual render result for export
[image]

Comment: it's very hard to understand what is your object, where is your light, etc... I guess you didn't put the sun into the object because as you must know it's not the way sun works

Comment: yes i didnt put the sun in the object

Comment: The placement for a *sun* light in the 3D environgent makes no difference. Try using a point light or other source.

Comment: nope same result

Comment: are you using a glass shader?

Comment: Yes I am using a glass shader

Answer (score 0):

I found out if I select all objects in a scene and hit "W" I go to clear all restrict blender. The lights are shown!